# How to prevent people bypassing my server cache?

Tags: caching, shopify, bots, cloudflare

I own a Shopify store that does flash sales. It uses cloudflare to manage the server caching of my products.json file. However, it seems like people are able to monitor my products.json and bypass the cache. I want the cache there because it reduces server load and also prevents people from botting my sales because they can't see exactly when I update my products.

They are constantly receiving `X-Cache: miss` when I'm expecting to return `hit, server`.

Does anyone know how they might be doing this and how I can go about stopping it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but shouldn't the cache be invalidated and thus useless once you make changes to the shop?

Comment: @Potaito Yes that's sort of the point. I don't want the new products to show up instantly in products.json because then people using a bot to monitor my site will see them very fast. I want to give manual users a chance.

Comment: Ah so your `products.json` leaks the information before the products become actually visible in the store. Try rephrasing your question a little bit to make that clearer :)

Answer (score 2):

know you all are looking for a cache bypass

Answer (score 1):

There's a thread in the Shopify community forum regarding calls to the products.json file: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/product-json-API/td-p/328448